# Replace string in R with patterns and replacements both vectors

Tags: r, string, vector

Let's say I have two vectors like so:

```
a <- c("this", "is", "test")
b <- c("that", "was", "boy")
```

I also have a string variable like so:

```
string <- "this is a story about a test"
```

I want to replace values in string so that it becomes the following:

```
string <- "that was a story about a boy"
```

I could do this using a for loop but I want this to be vectorized. How should I do this?

Answer (score 10):

If you're open to using a non-base package, `stringi` will work really well here:

```
stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(string, a, b, vectorize_all = FALSE)
#[1] "that was a story about a boy"
```

Note that this also works the same way for input strings of length > 1.

To be on the safe side, you can adapt this - similar to RUser's answer - to check for word boundaries before replacing:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(string, paste0("\\b", a, "\\b"), b, vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

This would ensure that you don't accidentally replace `his` with `hwas`, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some solutions.  They each will work even if `string` is a character vector of strings in which case substitutions will be done on each component of it.

**1) Reduce**  This uses no packages.

```
Reduce(function(x, i) gsub(paste0("\\b", a[i], "\\b"), b[i], x), seq_along(a), string)
## [1] "that was a story about a boy"
```

**2) gsubfn** `gsubfn` is like `gsub` but the replacement argument can be a list of substitutions (or certain other objects).

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\w+", setNames(as.list(b), a), string)
## [1] "that was a story about a boy"
```

**3) loop**  This isn't vectorized but have added for comparison.  No packages are used.

```
out <- string
for(i in seq_along(a)) out <- gsub(paste0("\\b", a[i], "\\b"), b[i], out)
out
## [1] "that was a story about a boy"
```

**Note:** There is some question of whether cycles are possible. For example, if

```
a <- c("a", "A")
b <- rev(a)
```

do we want

- "a" to be replaced with "A" and then back to "a" again, or
- "a" and "A" to be swapped.

All the solutions shown above assume the first case.   If we wanted the second case then perform the operation twice.  We will illustrate with (2) because it is the shortest but the same idea applies to them all:

```
# swap "a" and "A"
a <- c("a", "A")
b <- rev(a)

tmp <- gsubfn("\\w+", setNames(as.list(seq_along(a)), a), string)
gsubfn("\\w+", setNames(as.list(b), seq_along(a)), tmp)
## [1] "this is A story about A test"
```

Comment: Nice! I had not yet been exposed to Reduce. Many thanks.

Comment: Have added a Note regarding cycles

Comment: Also `regmatches(string, gregexpr(paste(a,collapse="|"), string)) <- list(b)` will work similarly to `gsubfn`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - I did say similarly. Of course it needs the `\\b` for word boundaries specifed as well, just like the `gsub` solution.

Comment: @thelatemail, It's longer and more complex, it overwrites the input and to fix it so that it works like (2) the regular expression is significantly more complex than in (2).  It does have the benefit that it uses no packages.

Answer (score 3):

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_replace_all_regex(string, "\\b" %s+% a %s+% "\\b", b, vectorize_all=FALSE)
#[1] "that was a story about a boy"
```

Answer (score 2):

Chipping in as well with a little function that relies only on `R base`:

```
repWords <- function(string,toRep,Rep,sep='\\s'){

  wrds <- unlist(strsplit(string,sep))
  ix <- match(toRep,wrds)
  wrds[ix] <- Rep  
  return(paste0(wrds,collapse = ' '))

}

a <- c("this", "is", "test")
b <- c("that", "was", "boy")

string <- "this is a story about a test"

> repWords(string,a,b)
[1] "that was a story about a boy"
```

Note:

This assumes you have a matching number of replacements. You can define the separator with `sep`.

Answer (score 2):

Talking of external packages, here's another one:

```
a <- c("this", "is", "test")
b <- c("that", "was", "boy")
x <- "this is a story about a test"


library(qdap)
mgsub(a,b,x)
```

which gives:

```
 "that was a story about a boy"
```

Comment: nice one! `mgsub` can make life a bit easier it seems

Comment: If `a <- "a"; b <- "A"`  then it transforms `about` to `About` which seems incorrect.